# Is there a comma needed in this sentence, and if so, why?

Tags: grammar, semantics

The sentence in question: "I met with a psychologist to see if I was on the autism spectrum but they told me that I was not."

- Is this a complete sentence: "They told me that I was not." And if so, why?
- Is there a comma needed before "but" in this sentence?
- Is the word "that" ungrammatical?

Comment: The sentence is a little clunky, but putting a comma there is mostly a style issue...my suggestion would be to put ";however, they told me I was not"..That said, writing suggestion are generally considered off-topic.

Comment: @Cascabel_StandWithUkraine What makes the sentence clunky? Do you have any references that I could read regarding this style issue? I was told not using a comma makes the sentence grammatically incorrect.

Comment: Punctuation is generally considered to be a style issue, and has little to do with grammar. Whoever told you that is not a grammarian  We have some recommendations for style guides, but you need check to EL&U.meta.SE for which are acceptable.

Comment: @Cascabel_StandWithUkraine I was deducted points on an assignment by a professor. The grade was later reverted after I argued the point. Yes, I am on reddit. I posted the same question.

Comment: As a general guide, I'd see *I met* then *they told me* and I'd be reaching for a comma. Only little sentences skip that comma: I met you and they told me I wouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

"They told me that I was not." would be an elliptical sentence. Normally a subject complement would be needed.  But this can be understood from context. In the given context the complement is "on the autism spectrum".

A comma may help this sentence.  It is fairly long and it is formed of two part, both of which contain a verb. It's probably not absolutely necessary, but it would help the reader break up the sentence.

The word that is correct, but may be omitted with no change in meaning.

Answer (score 0):

According to standard grammar, a comma is required.

> The word but is one of seven words that are referred to as coordinating conjunctions. We have a great guide to coordinating conjunctions, but the short version is that a coordinating conjunction is used to link two identical grammatical elements (i.e. nouns and nouns, verbs and verbs, etc). One key rule of grammar is that coordinating conjunctions that link independent clauses must have a comma before them. If a coordinating conjunction is linking anything else, it doesn’t need a comma.

"I met with a psychologist to see if I was on the autism spectrum" and "they told me that I was not" would both be independent sentences on their own, so they are independent clauses. The word "not" is standing in here for the phrase "not on the autism spectrum".